# Number of ways to sum $1$s, $2$s and $3$s, taking into account the order

Tags: number-theory, summation, integers

Say I have a number $n$. I want to see how many different ways I can create this number, where the order of my operations matter as well. For example I would for $n=3$ get the solutions $1+1+1$, $1+2$, $2+1$ and $3$, i.e. $4$ different solutions. From what I can tell, similar questions on here only care about the solutions to $1a + 2b + 3c = n$, with no respect to order.

Comment: Btw general Stars and Bars solution would consider $2 + 1$ different from $1 + 2$. In fact you need to do more work to get to a solution where they are not considered different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $a_n$ ways to form $n$, the recurrence is $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$ because you can either form $n-1$ and add a $1$, or ...  This is the recurrence for the Tribonacci numbers.  The sequence starting from $n=0$ starts
$$ 1, 1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705, 3136, 5768, 10609$$
and is given in [OEIS A000073](http://oeis.org/A000073).  You can find much more on this site if you search or in the OEIS entry